# MUI Icon: Module not found: Can't resolve '@emotion/react' in '.../@mui/styled-engine'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want Use MUI icons in my ReactJs project but when I start my project, I have an error.

Install MUI with npm install `@mui/icons-material` ...
Import My Icon:

```
import HomeIcon from '@mui/icons/material/Home';
```

How Can I Solve This Error?

[image: this is my error]

Error text:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@emotion/react' in '.../@mui/styled-engine'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the installation guide [here](https://mui.com/getting-started/installation/#main-content), you're missing those 2 styling packages in v5.

The icons from `@mui/icons-material` package [depends on](https://mui.com/components/icons/#material-icons) the `SvgIcon` component which comes from `@mui/material`. The component itself uses [`styled()`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-material/src/SvgIcon/SvgIcon.js#L7) and by default it uses emotion under the hood which means if you use MUI icons you need to install these 2 packages below too (aside from installing `@mui/material`):

```
npm install @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you imported it wrong. I am using the following packages:

```
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.1",
"@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.48",
"@mui/material": "^5.0.1",
```

and I have imported the icon you want by using:

```
import HomeIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Home';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).